# How get custom post with taxanomy?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, taxonomy

I know, that I have to use the class `wp_query` and a loop, but I can't get the custom post from the database with taxonomy, example, category documents. I was reading, that I had to use the template 'taxonomy-{slug}', but I dont know, how I can get posts of this taxonomy.

For example, I am clicking the link http://mysite/categorydocuments/private' and I am getting the post with post_type 'documents' and taxonomy categorydocuments''.

How can I get the taxonomy `private` and put this taxonomy in my $args for `Wp_query`? Please, don`t offer me the variable with parse link.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `$post_type` to your custom post type name if you are using a custom post type

```
$post_type = 'post';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

  // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
  $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

  foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

    $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

    if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
        //Do you general query loop here  
    endwhile; endif;

  endforeach;

endforeach;
```